# Why is there no output when entering # in bash

Tags: bash

I have stumbled across an unexplained symbol in bash... How come when I enter the symbol `#`, I don't get `#: command not found`??? Is this because `#` is a comment in bash?

Comment: Yes. `#` is the `bash` comment character.

Comment: I guess I never realized that using the bash shell is the same thing as what interprets my bash scripts... Wow, I feel foolish :0

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Directly from `man bash`:

> ### COMMENTS
>
> In a non-interactive shell, or an interactive shell in which the `interactive_comments` option to the `shopt` builtin is enabled (see *SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS* below), **a word beginning with `#` causes that word and all remaining characters on that line to be ignored**.
>   An interactive shell without the `interactive_comments` option enabled does not allow comments. The `interactive_comments` option is on by default in interactive shells.

Comment: This is useful when you're copy-and-pasting snippets (which may have comments) into an interactive shell.